# How can I add a label and textbox to fill a horizontal panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I already have some split containers set up and a panel that is about the height for a textbox and a label.  I'd like the label to be left of the textbox and the textbox's width to basically go to the edge of the panel (like stretch to the right).

Is there a simple way to do this using a flowlayoutpanel or tablepanel or something.  I'm adding the controls programatically (not using forms editor).

Ideally the textbox should stretch if the panel grows.

Comment: Look up the `Dock`, `Anchor` and `Size` properties in C#.  I presume this is Winforms?

Comment: You should be able to actually encompass those component controls directly into your *Panel*.  Then assign the *Dock or Anchor* attribute to position. So, yes... You can.

Comment: I was trying to use a flowlayoutpanel.  Dock and Anchor seem to be difficult to get working.  This is Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is calculate the label and textbox's width and height based on the panels dimensions.

For position, you may well have to just give them a hardcoded starting position, but again, this could be based off of some calculations.

If they're placed in a panel within a tablelayoutpanel then they should automatically resize themself if the form / container controller grows, but to be sure you could use the anchor property to ensure this.

for example, dock the panel to fill mode within the tablelayoutpanel cell, then assuming you have the label on the left and textbox on the right, anchor the label left, and the textbox right. This should ensure that these edges of the control stay glued to the panel on these sides.

Answer (score 0):

When you deviate from the *Form Designer View* your code will be slightly more specific.  When you utilize the designer your able to implement such a thing by dragging and dropping. But in order to do such a thing in code you would do something such as:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 358);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.panel1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.panel1_Paint);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "label1";
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(47, 0);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(353, 20);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(424, 382);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.panel1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

As you can see at runtime the components are initialized; then all the attributes are assigned proper positioning.  Your marking the layout relative to the *Form* and the *Panel*.  By defining the points you can ensure that they centralized.

This should get you started; but in no way will be ideal.  You may need to configure such an item differently to ensure it meets your criteria. But with a *Form* at 440 x 420 pixels. The Panel also docked within a half inch of the entire layout.  Your textbox and label are anchored to the upper left and right portion of the screen.

Keep in mind if you maximize this layout it may tweak the design in an unfavorable manner unless they are locked to those specific positions. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I got the same answer as this.